# Obtain LWP id from a pthread_t on Solaris to use with processor_bind

Tags: pthreads, solaris, setthreadaffinitymask

On Solaris, `processor_bind` is used to set affinity for threads.  You need to know the LWPID of the target thread or use the constant `P_MYID` to refer to yourself.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
void set_affinity(pthread_t thr, int cpu_number)
{
   id_t lwpid = what_do_I_call_here(thr);
   processor_bind(P_LWPID, lwpid, cpu_number, NULL);
}
```

In reality my function has a bunch of cross platform stuff in it that I've elided for clarity.

The key point is that I'd like to set the affinity of an arbitrary pthread_t so I can't use `P_MYID`.

How can I achieve this using `processor_bind` or an alternative interface?

Comment: that would be equivalent to `P_MYID`; neither `pthread_self()` nor `P_MYID` could have been used in that code because it needed to be able to operate on an arbitrary target thread, not just itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on this, and due to my confusion:

The lwpid is what is created by

```
pthread_create( &lwpid, NULL, some_func, NULL);
```

Thread data is available externally to a process that is not the one making the `pthread_create()` call - via the `/proc` interface

```
/proc/<pid>/lwp/<lwpid>/    lwpid == 1 is the main thread, 2 .. n are the lwpid in the above example.
```

But this tells you almost nothing about which thread you are dealing with, except that it is the lwpid in the example above.

```
/proc/pid/lwp/lwpid/lwpsinfo
```

can be read into a struct lwpsinfo which has some more information, from which you might be able to ascertain if you are looking at the thread you want.  see `/usr/include/sys/procfs.h`

Or `man -s 4 proc`

Comment: is pthread_create() guaranteed to map the lwpid -> pthread_t on Solaris 10 and 11?

Comment: pthread_t is a datatype.  The first argument of pthread_create modifies argument 1 to the value of the lwpid for the thread SUCCESSFULLY created.  Yes guaranteed.  In both Solaris 10 and 11. /usr/include/sys/types.h:typedef        uint_t  pthread_t;      /* = thread_t in thread.h */

Answer (score 0):

The Solaris 11 kernel has critical threads optimization. You setup which threads require special care, the kernel does the rest.  This appears to be what you want.  Please read this short explanation to see if I understood what you want.

```
https://blogs.oracle.com/observatory/entry/critical_threads_optimization
```

The above is an alternate.  It may not fly at all for you.  But is the preferred mechanism, per Oracle.

For Solaris 10, use the `pthread_t tid` of the LWP with  an `idtype_t` of `P_LWPID` in your call to `processor_bind`.  This works in Solaris 8 -> 11.  It works ONLY for LWP's in the process.  It is not clear to me if that is your model.

HTH